# Divide picture in four forms

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image: Figure]

I  try  to  divide  this  picture  in  four identic  forms  up  to isometry. It  is  possible? I  seen  that  there  exist  some simetries  but  doesn't  helped  me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

(This space intentionally left blank.)

Comment: @JohnWatson: It just took a couple of minutes of tinkering. The four four-unit long "base" segments seemed like an obvious place to start. I drew a few lines from the ends of the top and bottom bases to match the sides of the left and right bases. (I made a guess that the pieces would be merely *rotated*, not *flipped*.) These new lines, as additional edges of the left and right figures, prompted more matching lines on the top and bottom, and so forth, until the dissection was complete.